# Soma de valores de coluna MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tcc2`.`catalogo` (
`idPHL` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`isbn` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`titulo` LONGTEXT ,
`autor` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`edicao` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`anoPublicacao` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`editora` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`qtdEx` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idPHL`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tcc2`.`disciplina_livros` (
`livro` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`disciplina` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`tipoReferencia` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`livro`, `disciplina`),
INDEX `fk_catalogo_has_disciplina_disciplina1_idx` (`disciplina` ASC),
INDEX `fk_catalogo_has_disciplina_catalogo1_idx` (`livro` ASC),
INDEX `fk_disc_livro_tipo_idx` (`tipoReferencia` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_disc_disciplina`
FOREIGN KEY (`disciplina`)
REFERENCES `tcc2`.`disciplina` (`codDisciplina`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_disc_livro_tipo`
FOREIGN KEY (`tipoReferencia`)
REFERENCES `tcc2`.`tipoReferencia` (`idTipoRef`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_disciplina_catalogo`
FOREIGN KEY (`livro`)
REFERENCES `tcc2`.`catalogo` (`idPHL`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tcc2`.`tipoReferencia` (
`idTipoRef` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`descricao` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idTipoRef`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tcc2`.`disciplina` (
`codDisciplina` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`codDisciplina`));
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta onde sejam retornados o nome da disciplina, o titulo, a quantidade de exemplares e a soma da quantidade de exemplares. Estou tentando o seguinte:

```
select d.nome, ca.titulo, ca.qtdEx, sum(ca.qtdEx) from catalogo as ca, disciplina_livros as dl,
disciplina as d
where dl.disciplina = 'EDU140' and ca.idPHL = dl.livro and
dl.tipoReferencia = 1
group by ca.titulo;
```

O resultado é como abaixo, a coluna `sum(ca.qtdEx)` deveria retornar 18 e não 324.

Modelagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para retornar a soma da coluna qtdEx?

Comment: Utilize joins para juntar as tabelas da sua consulta e insira TODOS os campos que não fazer parte da soma dentro do group by. Provavelmente você obterá o resultado esperado ou uma série de linhas duplicadas que estão sujando esse resultado.

Comment: Não entendi a parte do join.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294311/difference-between-these-two-joining-table-approaches

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Pode criar uma view para simplificar a consulta e na consulta da view fazer a soma, veja [aqui um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22081/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-criar-uma-view-no-mysql-pegando-dados-de-4-ou-mais-tabelas-difere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez o retorno da consulta sendo somente o número de livros no estoque de uma determinada disciplina seja uma melhor maneira de realizar essa consulta

### Query

```
SELECT D.NOME AS DISCIPLINA ,sum(CA.qtdEx) AS QNT_LIVROS FROM
     CATALOGO CA,
     DISCIPLINA_LIVROS DL,
     DISCIPLINA D
WHERE
     CA.idPHL = DL.LIVRO AND 
     DL.DISCIPLINA = D.codDisciplina 
GROUP BY D.nome
```

### Exemplo de retorno de estoque

```
+-------------+------------+
| DISCIPLINA  | QNT_LIVROS |
+-------------+------------+
| Matemática  |          1 |
| programação |         33 |
+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Se você quiser também dá para saber quantos livros há por disciplina

### Query

```
SELECT D.NOME AS DISCIPLINA ,count(CA.titulo) AS QNT_LIVROS FROM 
    CATALOGO CA, 
    DISCIPLINA_LIVROS DL, 
    DISCIPLINA D 
WHERE 
    CA.idPHL = DL.LIVRO AND 
    DL.DISCIPLINA = D.codDisciplina 
GROUP BY D.nome;
```

### Exemplo de retorno

```
+-------------+------------+
| DISCIPLINA  | QNT_LIVROS |
+-------------+------------+
| Matemática  |          1 |
| programação |          2 |
+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Com essa sintaxe a sum(ca.qtdEX) retorna os mesmos valores de CA.qtdEx.

Comment: Se você puder mandar o diagrama dessas tabelas com todas colunas, ficaria mais fácil para mim fazer a query e tentar te ajudar

Comment: Editei Reynaldo Mansi